# hadoop_mapreduce_wordcount string to text or text to string

Tags: hadoop

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM F
WHERE A = 'Lee'

I want to make this query into code using wordcount example.

```
public class WordCountDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");      
        job.setJarByClass(WordCountDriver.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}

public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                context.write(new Text(itr.nextToken()), one);
            }
        }
    }

public class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;

        Text a;
        String convertkey;
        convertkey = "Lee";
        a = new Text(convertkey);

        if( key == a){

        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
        }
    }
}
```

but if loop doesn't work. :(
it can't work 'if(k==a)' 
if i use 'if(k!=a)', it works.
why does it aware of k is not eqaul a??

Comment: You would want to do the filtering for name "lee" in the mapper, as a rule try and send as few keys as possible through the mapper down to the reducer. If the answer below was what you were looking for, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use ==.  Use the equals() method instead.  Be aware, though, that key is a Text and not a String like "Lee".  You need to use the toString() method for a Text to get a String to compare.